# Why is the function not returning lowercase letters?

Tags: c, lowercase

I'm currently new to C so how things work is still slightly alien to me as I come from an OOP background of Java. I'm trying to get an input from the terminal and then turn it into all lowercase letters however it seems the function isn't working. Any tips if possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int lower(int c){
  if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    return c + 'a' - 'A';
  else
    return c;
}

int main(){
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    lower(c);
    putchar(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `main` function isn't doing anything with the return-value of `lower`. If this was written in Java it would have the exact same bug, so I don't think there's anything "alien" about what's going on.

Comment: `lower(c)` -> `c = lower(c)`. `lower(c);` just calls the function and then does nothing with the returned value.

Comment: Your program does not convert accented uppercase characters to lowercase, btw.

Comment: How would you write this in java BTW?

Comment: @Dai can `getchar` read an accented character?

Comment: Don't overlook the standard libary function `c = tolower(c);`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Depending on your configured C locale, I believe so, yes. For example, `char` can represent all characters in [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), which includes accented uppercase characters. You can reproduce this bug in the console by using Alt+NumPad codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should use the return values of `lower`:

```
putchar(lower(c));
```

You may also like to use the standard library function [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower).

Comment: Wow it was such a silly mistake haha, yeah I just realised I wasn't using the returned value. Appreciate it!